# Windows 7 Bitlocker disabled but still prompting

Tags: windows-7, windows, encryption, bitlocker

My windows 7 bitlocker is disabled, but in the event log i am still getting errors on Bitlocker, and when I reboot I get "Back up your encryption key" prompts.

Is there a setting in the registry or somewhere that I can fully disable Bitlocker?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try disabling the service.

1. Start > Run
2. "services.msc", enter
3. Scroll to Bitlocker service
4. Right-click, properties
5. Startup type: Disabled

Comment: Currently it's set to Manual start, and it's not started, yet I am being prompted to backup my key. I'll set it to disable and see.

Anything else to check on?

Comment: It's been a while, and it hasn't happened, so I'll mark this complete.

Answer (score -1):

Go to your registry type in Bitlocker, disable the Bitlocker about four in a row going down. Reboot your computer and wha la, u have disabled bitlocker. Now when Windows boots up repair what files that are corrupt. Pretty easy when you are going to install new Windows, as a matter of fact if you installed Windows 10 use your original windows to complete the bitlocker registry disablement, pick install a driver, or image, which ever one pulls up Windows Security power shell, also you will be able to reformat your operating system drive. Rename the drive OS (?)...

Comment: **Danger!** Destroying whatever Registry keys happen to mention BitLocker is very likely to cause more critical problems. Please include some specific entries that should be changed and why.